# How to use a special while loop in tsql, do while numeric

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, while-loop, azure-sql-database

I'm loading some quite nasty data through Azure data factory

This is how the data looks after being loaded, existing of 2 parts:
1. Metadata of a test
2. Actual measurements of the test  -> the measurement is numeric

Image I have about 10 times such 'packages' of 1.Metadata + 2.Measurements

[image]

What I would like it to be / what I'm looking for is the following:
The number column with 1,2,.... is what I'm looking for!

[image]

Imagine my screenshot could go no further but this goes along until id=10
I guess a while loop is necessary here...

Query before:

```
SELECT Field1 FROM Input
```

Query after:

```
SELECT GeneratedId, Field1 FROM Input
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

EDIT: added a hint:
[image]

Comment: Laurens - it seems like you will need to do this in the data factory code. Can you manipulate your input processing to differentiate between metadata+measurement collections?

Comment: Thanks. The problem is, I've never worked with Data Factory, so I'd rather tackle this on the side of SQL ?  
In Data Factory I reading out a folder with 10 of these files... this is the result in SQL as you can imagine

Comment: Is the first record of each package always `Title ...`?

Comment: Yes, kind of stupid of me not noticing that :)

Comment: @laurens - not sure SQL will consistently feed you back your data in the order you import it (unless you add an identity column during import). The result of which is, any query against the aggregated data can't be assured to be in the order you expect it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution, this requires SQL-SERVER 2012 or later.

Start by getting an `Id` column on your data. If you can do this previous to the script that would be even better, but if not, try something like this...

```
CREATE TABLE #InputTable (
    Id INT IDENTITY(1, 1),
    TestData NVARCHAR(MAX) )

INSERT INTO #InputTable (TestData)
SELECT Field1 FROM Input
```

Now create a query to get the `GeneratedId` of each package as well as the `Id` where they start and end. You can do this by getting all the records `LIKE 'title%'` since that is the first record of each package, then using [`ROW_NUMBER`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql), `Id`, and [`LEAD`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql) for the `GeneratedId`, `StartId`, and `EndId` respectively.

```
SELECT
    GeneratedId = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (Id)),
    StartId = Id,
    EndId = LEAD(Id) OVER (ORDER BY (Id))
FROM #InputTable
WHERE TestData LIKE 'title%'
```

Lastly, join this to the input in order to get all the records, with the correct `GeneratedId`.

```
SELECT
    package.GeneratedId, i.TestData
FROM (
    SELECT
        GeneratedId = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (Id)),
        StartId = Id,
        EndId = LEAD(Id) OVER (ORDER BY (Id))
    FROM #InputTable
    WHERE TestData LIKE 'title%' ) package
INNER JOIN #InputTable i 
    ON i.Id >= package.StartId 
    AND (package.EndId IS NULL OR i.Id < package.EndId)
```

Comment: when seeing it like that, it looks so easy... but if you don't have tsql that much in the fingers. Thanks a lot!! This is it